# Bing map, disappear custom pins

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, position, location, bing-maps

So, i have a problem with a bing map, i want to put  custom pins (image) to the map but i don't see all of the pins just a few and when i'm zooming the pins are disappear

This is my code:

```
foreach (Stores store in boltok)
        {
            var myPosition = new Windows.Devices.Geolocation.BasicGeoposition();
            myPosition.Latitude = store.Latitude;
            myPosition.Longitude = store.Longitude;
            var myStorePoint = new Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geopoint(myPosition);
            MapIcon icon = new MapIcon();
            icon.Location = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
            {
                Latitude = store.Latitude,
                Longitude = store.Longitude
            });
            icon.Visible = true;
            icon.ZIndex = 0;
            icon.Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/StoreFinder/Pin.png"));
            icon.NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 1.0);

            myMapControl.MapElements.Add(icon);
            myMapControl.Children.Add(icon);

        }
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

When using MapIcon's only add them to the MapElements property, not the children property. MapIcon's are designed with some collision detection on them and will hide when a bunch are overlapping. As you zoom in they should reappear. If you don't want this then create a UserControl to use as a pushpin and add it to the maps Children's property. Take a look at the "Show XAML elements on the map control" section of this documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn792121.aspx